# Is it possible to call functions from contracts within a migration on Truffle?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, ganache

Is it possible to call functions from contracts within a migration? I try to interact with a contract that has already been deployed by another migration, but truffle doesn't recognize that this function exists within the contract!
If migrations can't call contract functions, how do I interact with the contract without using truffle develop?

My migration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91gRE.png)

Truffle:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcBm3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

let myNewContract = await MyNewContract.at((await MyOldContract.deployed()).address);

That will create an object using your new logic contract that is located at the address of your proxy (the permanent address).